# Pivot table column name and Horizontal Bar in Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

Ugh. As you can see, my pivot table has a problem - I probably don't understand pivot tables very well in that case.

I want the pivot table to state "Months" in the first column and not "Row Labels".

Also, I'd like to have a horizontal line appear at an exact percentage in my chart. How would I do that?

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Please note that SO is for programming questions; this may be better suited for https://superuser.com/. That said, pivot charts are extremely fiddly IMO... you may be better off creating the table formulaically and creating a regular chart on top of it.

Comment: question now on [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1684191/pivot-table-column-name-and-horizontal-bar-in-pivot-chart/1684194)